# How to have KendoPanel's all the sections expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-panelbar

I just started using KendoPanel and I am wanting to expand all the segments of the panel under certain condition. I am using following code to achieve that:

```
var panelbar = $("#KendoPanel").kendoPanelBar();
                    var kendoPanelbar = panelbar.data().kendoPanelBar;
                    kendoPanelbar.collapse($("li", panelbar.element));
```

Seems like it is **contracting** all the segments instead of **expanding** them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmm collapse? why u no use expand? `kendoPanelbar.expand($("li", panelbar.element));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below code snippet.

```
<ul id="mypanelbar">
    <li class="k-state-active">First Item
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub Item 1</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 2</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 3</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 4</li>
                </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Second Item
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub Item 1</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 2</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 3</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 4</li>
                </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Third Item
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub Item 1</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 2</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 3</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 4</li>
                </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Fourth Item
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub Item 1</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 2</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 3</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 4</li>
                </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Fifth Item
                <ul>
                    <li>Sub Item 1</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 2</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 3</li>
                    <li>Sub Item 4</li>
                </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    var panelBar;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        panelBar = $("#mypanelbar").kendoPanelBar().data("kendoPanelBar");
        // Expand all item
        panelBar.expand($("#mypanelbar li.k-item"));
    });
</script>
```

Let me know if any concern.